# Scale and crop image in XML

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview

I'm trying to scale and crop image at the same time and show it from left to right screen edge. I receive image that is just little bit wider than users screen and I'm able to scale it like this (XML):

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/category_image_top"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="170dp"
        android:maxHeight="170dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true" 
        android:focusable="false"
        />
```

But this is what I get:
[image: What I get]

I would like to align image to top right like so:
[image: What I want]

Is this possible? I've tried all scaleTypes but noting works, image is either scaled to fit by X and Y (fitXY, fitStart) or image cropped but centered (centerCrop). I need something like android:scaleType="cropStart"

Comment: It might be easier to do it in code than xml before you set the image, then you'll have more fine grained control

Comment: Yes, code is my option b. But it's strange to me that this is something that can't be solved in view (at least I can't :)). If you have option to fit image regarding star, why can't you crop image on start?

Answer (score 5):

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/category_image_top"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="170dp"
        android:maxHeight="170dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:paddingLeft="half of your screen width"
        android:paddingBottom="half of your screen height"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true" 
        android:focusable="false"
/>
```

You can set padding to move image left or right and also top and bottom padding to move up and down

Comment: `android:scaleType="centerCrop"` was my solution, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As I didn't find a way to deal with this situation through xml (views) I turned (as @serenskye suggested) to code. Here's my code, I hope it helps (ps: I've changed my logic a little bit, I wanted to fit image by width so I've scaled it to predefined imageWidght and then cropped it to imageHeight)

```
//bm is received image (type = Bitmap)
Bitmap scaledImage = null;
float scaleFactor = (float) bm.getWidth() / (float) imageWidth;

//if scale factor is 1 then there is no need to scale (it will stay the same)
if (scaleFactor != 1) {
    //calculate new height (with ration preserved) and scale image
    int scaleHeight = (int) (bm.getHeight() / scaleFactor);                     
    scaledImage = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bm, imageWidth, scaleHeight, false);
}
else {
    scaledImage = bm;
}

Bitmap cropedImage = null;
//if cropped height is bigger then image height then there is no need to crop
if (scaledImage.getHeight() > imageHeight)
    cropedImage = Bitmap.createBitmap(scaledImage, 0, 0, imageWidth, imageHeight);
else
    cropedImage = scaledImage;

iv.setImageBitmap(cropedImage);
```

Answer (score 0):

add

```
android:layout_gravity="center"
```